# HTML5 Canvas, Tileset won't show up

Tags: javascript, dictionary, canvas

My tileset won't show up. What is the problem?­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

Here is a code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <style>
    body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }

    #mapa {
        border: solid 1px;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body> <canvas id="mapa" height="500px" width="500px"></canvas>
    <script>
    var canvas = document.getElementById('mapa');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var trawa = new Image();
    trawa.src = "trawa.png";
    var mapa = [
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    ];
    var posX = 0;
    var posY = 0;
    for (var x = 0; x < mapa.length; x++) {
        for (var y = 0; y < mapa[x].length; y++) {
            if (mapa[x][y] == 0) {
                ctx.drawImage(trawa, posX, posY, 32, 32);
            }
            posX += 50;
        }
        posX = 0;
        posY += 50;
    }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If you have an issue with your code, **include it** in the question, and explain what it does with a context to the issue you're having with it

Comment: Please don't add code via a pastebin link that could become invalid at any future date, there are facilities in the stackoverflow question editor window to put HTML/Javascript embedded in your question, viewers can then even _run_ your code without having to leave this tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that the image isn't loaded yet when you try to draw it, what you need to do is to wait until it is loaded.

For that you can use `trawa.onload` as following:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
  body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
  }
#mapa
{
  border: solid 1px;
}
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<canvas id = "mapa" height = "500px" width= "500px"></canvas>

<script>

var canvas = document.getElementById('mapa');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var trawa = new Image();
trawa.src = "trawa.png";


var mapa = [
[0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
];
var posX = 0;
var posY = 0;

trawa.onload = function (){
  for (var x = 0; x < mapa.length; x++){

    for (var y = 0; y < mapa[x].length; y++)
    {

      if (mapa[x][y] == 0)
      {
        ctx.drawImage(trawa, posX, posY, 32,32);
      }

  posX+=50;

    }
    posX = 0;
    posY+=50;
  }

}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```